# Objective-C - How to add static first cell in UICollectionview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, collectionview

I want to make the first cell fixed.

So, I made 2 section and write like this

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(section == 0){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return self.assetsFetchResults.count;
    }

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 2;
}


#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegate
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//    NSInteger currentTag = cell.tag + 1;
//    
//    cell.tag = currentTag;
//    NSLog(@"cell tag %d" , cell.tag);

    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        PhotoLibraryFirstCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PhotoLibraryFirstCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
    }else{
        PhotoLibraryCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PhotoLibraryCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        PHAsset *asset = self.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item];
        [self.imageManager requestImageForAsset:asset
                                     targetSize:AssetGridThumbnailSize
                                    contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                        options:nil
                                  resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
//                                      cell.imageView.image = result;
                                  }];
        return cell;
    }
```

But if I write like this

Space is created between 0 section and 1 section like this image.

How can I attach section 0 and section 1?

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, you should keep all cells in a section. Instead of checking `indexPath.section == 0` you should check `indexPath.item == 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to add another section in collection view , instead use the same section. Keep the first row static by the following check I made in the code.

```
 - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
         return self.assetsFetchResults.count+1;

    }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
        return 1;
    }


    #pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegate
    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //    NSInteger currentTag = cell.tag + 1;
    //    
    //    cell.tag = currentTag;
    //    NSLog(@"cell tag %d" , cell.tag);

        if(indexPath.row == 0){
            PhotoLibraryFirstCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PhotoLibraryFirstCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            return cell;
        }else{
            PhotoLibraryCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PhotoLibraryCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            PHAsset *asset = self.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item-1];
            [self.imageManager requestImageForAsset:asset
                                         targetSize:AssetGridThumbnailSize
                                        contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                            options:nil
                                      resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
    //                                      cell.imageView.image = result;
                                      }];
            return cell;
        }
```